# Is xfstt necessary?

Tags: init.d

I am using *Lubuntu 11.10*. Every time when I shutdown the system I can read on the black screen an error for trying to stop `xfstt`. I found info about this process [here](http://freecode.com/projects/xfstt). I have `K20xfstt` in `/etc/rc0.d` and also in other folders.

But I don't know if it is necessary. Probably I installed it during the installation of Maple or Java. I don't know!

So, nowadays is necessary to use it or may I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xfstt` is the "X11 Font Server for True Type Fonts", so unless you don't want fancy fonts, don't remove it.  X11 may break without it.

Comment: OK. Thanks, but yesterday I tried to remove using `apt-get remove`. Since that everything is working until now. I am not seeing any change on my laptop. Maybe Lubuntu does not make use of this font server. Lets see.